# How to get the distance to a sound source using a 2 channel hydrophone array (bearing)?

Tags: pamguard, array, localization

I am going to use a 2 channel hydrophone array during some boat surveys. I will be collecting GPS data as well and I heard that with the bearing and the change in location pamguard can estimate the distance to a sound source. How can this be done?

Thank you in advance:)

Comment: Is this question related to the other (soundtrap) question?

Comment: There are a variety of methods for achieving this, even within PAMGuard. Stack Exchange/Overflow is all about helping those who help themselves, so you might get a better response if you're able to showing your prior work and share what you've already tried. A good place to start would be the documentation within PAMGuard (Help->Help->Localisation->Generic Localisers).

Comment: To build on @BrianMiller comment, is this question seeking an answer on the theory of getting a bearing and eventual location using Pamguard, or the exact analytical process?